# How to bind XML data to RadioButtonList using XmlDocument?

Tags: asp.net, xml, c#-4.0

I'm stumped here. I've dynamically created RadioButtonLists before using data from a database, but not from XML. I'm not sure if I'm suppose to use the same method, but what I have so far isn't working. Here's what I have (stAddress is the value I'm getting from the user):

```
XmlDocument xAddress = new XmlDocument();
xAddress.Load("http://myxmlservice/geocode?address=" + stAddress);
XmlNodeList xNodeList = xAddress.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("response");
XmlNode address = xNodeList.Item(0).SelectSingleNode("address");
XmlNode latlong = xNodeList.Item(0).SelectSingleNode("latlng");

rbMultiAdd.DataSource = xNodeList;
rbMultiAdd.DataTextField = address.InnerText;
rbMultiAdd.DataValueField = latlong.InnerText;
rbMultiAdd.DataBind();
```

I keep getting an error on the DataBind() = "DataBinding: 'System.Xml.XmlElement' does not contain a property with the name '330 S Valley View Blvd'."

330 S Valley View Blvd is one of the results from my XML data.

Is there another way I should be doing this since the data is XML?

Thank you for any assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out using what @Josh posted as a reference.

```
XmlNodeList xNodeList = xAddress.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("response");

var addrs = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

foreach (XmlNode xNode in xNodeList)
{
   var xAddr = xNode["address"].InnerText;
   var xLatLng = xNode["latlng"].InnerText;
   addrs.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(xAddr, xLatLng));   
}
rbMultiAdd.DataSource = addrs;
rbMultiAdd.DataTextField = "Key";
rbMultiAdd.DataValueField = "Value";
rbMultiAdd.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        //Thanks Psykopup
    // Above code works fine for me when I Put "attributes" 

     string strSP = "USP_XML_StoredProcedure";
            cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = cnn;
            cmd.CommandText = strSP;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Id", DbType.Int32).Value = 28;

            XmlReader reader = cmd.ExecuteXmlReader();

            if (reader.Read())
            {
                xdoc.Load(reader);
            }

            XmlNodeList xNodeList = xdoc.SelectNodes("/Parent/REC");

            var source = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
            foreach (XmlNode xNode in xNodeList)
            {
                var xCode = ***xNode.Attributes***["ID"].InnerText;
                var xText = ***xNode.Attributes***["Name"].InnerText;
                source.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(xCode, xText));
            }

            rbListDistrict.DataSource = source;
            rbListDistrict.DataTextField = "Value";
            rbListDistrict.DataValueField = "Key";
            rbListDistrict.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

`DataTextField` and `DataValueField` both refer to property names on your object. Data binding uses reflection to look those up on the item that is being bound to.

In this case it is a `XmlNode` type. Which, as the error states doesn't have a property of type "330 S Valley View Blvd", which is the value of `InnerText`.

In this case you are probably going to have to project your list onto an intermediate type and use that for binding. There are many different ways to do this, here is one:

```
XmlNodeList xNodeList = xAddress.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("response");

var addresses = xNodeList.Select(n => new KeyValuePair<String, String>(
    n.SelectSingleNode("address"), n.SelectSingleNode("latlng")))
    .ToList();

rbMultiAdd.DataSource = addresses;
rbMultiAdd.DataTextField = "Key";
rbMultiAdd.DataValueField = "Value";
rbMultiAdd.DataBind();
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm getting an error that "XmlNodeList does not contain a definition for 'Select'"

Comment: `Enumerable.Select` is an extension method, and you will need to reference `System.Linq` in order to use it.

Comment: I actually already created the System.Linq namespace and I'm still getting that error. Not sure what's going on.